# [Unix/Mac OS][Apache][PHP] - change configuration File (php.ini) Path

Tags: php, macos, pdo, apache2, command-line-interface

I have two php.ini :

- one regular in /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
- one for my CLI /usr/lib/php.ini

The regular one works fine and load all the extensions I need, 
whereas the CLI one refuse to load some extensions (such as pdo.so) :

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so, 9):
>   image not found in Unknown on line 0

I'd like to change the Configuration File (php.ini) Path of my CLI to make it point on the regular one (and then solve the extension loading problem) but I can't find how to make it on an UNIX system.

Answer (score 0):

Make the second one a symbolic link to the first. This is done using:

```
ln -s [TARGET_FILE] [SYMLINK_NAME]
```

If your non-CLI php.ini is /etc/php.cgi.ini and your CLI php.ini is /etc/php.cli.ini, you'd be doing `ln -s /etc/php.cgi.ini /etc/php.cli.ini`

Comment: The CLI php.ini links on the regular one but still can't load the extensions : 

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Can you check where the actual PHP extension dir is pointing to on both CGI and CLI?

Comment: CGI is pointing /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525, CLI is pointing /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/

Comment: Then your problem is that you are using two completely different builds of PHP. Build both in the same fashion - or specify the extension dir explicitely in php.ini.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to specify another version of PHP to the CLI ? Is there a configuration file where I can specify it such httpd.conf for Apache in CGI ?